# How to select multiple lines that contain a specific word with regex?

Tags: regex

In Notepad++ i have a text something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nMhH.png

I want to select all lines with regex, which contains string "EMPLOYEES" and ends with ";"

Text to be selected:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID                             NUMBER(6,0)         NOT NULL,
  FIRST_NAME                              VARCHAR2(20)        NULL,
  LAST_NAME                               VARCHAR2(25)        NOT NULL,
  EMAIL                                   VARCHAR2(25)        NOT NULL,
  PHONE_NUMBER                            VARCHAR2(20)        NULL,
  HIRE_DATE                               DATE                NOT NULL,
  JOB_ID                                  VARCHAR2(10)        NOT NULL,
  SALARY                                  NUMBER(8,2)         NULL,
  COMMISSION_PCT                          NUMBER(2,2)         NULL,
  MANAGER_ID                              NUMBER(6,0)         NULL,
  DEPARTMENT_ID                           NUMBER(4,0)         NULL);

COMMENT ON TABLE EMPLOYEES IS 
'employees table. Contains 107 rows. References with departments, 
jobs, job_history tables. Contains a self reference.';
```

It works when there is only one line, for example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmwYO.png

...but i want to select lines mentioned above (contains a specific word ("EMPLOYEES") and ends with specific char (";"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex search in Notepad++:

```
Find: ^.*\bEMPLOYEES[\s\S]*?;
```

Explanation:

```
^              from the start of the line
    .*         match all content in that line until reaching
    \b         a word boundary
    EMPLOYEES  followed by 'EMPLOYEES'
    [\s\S]*?   match all content, this time across newlines, until reaching
    ;          the nearest semicolon
```

Comment: Thank you. This partially works, but it still doesn't select the start of the line. For example: COMMENT ON TABLE, CREATE TABLE, etc.

Comment: @zoki182 Thanks for the feedback, I have updated my answer, and tested in NPP.  It seems to be working.

Comment: THANK YOU very much, it works! :D Is there maybe a solution similar to this, to select all lines (that we are searching for) at once?  If not, this will work too.

Comment: @zoki182 Well you can do a find all in NPP, which might be along the lines of what you have in mind.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen  I've updated my post, can you please check/help me with that one..if there is solution.. :)

Comment: I have reverted your question because your follow-up invalidates my answer, which you already accepted some time ago.  I suggest opening a new question.

Comment: You can post the question and give my current regex as the starting point, but then mention what is wrong about it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your solution, but i just found that i need extra functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222762/discussion-between-zoki182-and-tim-biegeleisen).